# Sending post request to REST over SSL in json from C#

Tags: c#, json, ssl

I looked up every single page on google there was no clear answer
right now this is my code:

```
try
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.hesabit.com/oauth2/token");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

    string result_st;

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "{\"code\":\"{atho code}\"," +
                       "\"grant_type\":\"authorization_code\"," +
                       "\"client_id\":\"{client_id}\"," +
                       "\"client_secret\":\"{client_secret}\"," +
                       "\"redirect_uri\":\"{redirect_uri}\"}";
        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        result_st = result;
    }

    return result_st;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return ex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Google **has** a ton of page describing what you want to achieve : https://www.google.fr/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=jBU0WIjqDYLBaMXqoJAE&gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&q=sending+post+request+to+REST+over+SSL+in+json+from+C%23. Moreover, your post does not have a question.

Comment: For example http://www.json.org/JSONRequest.html

Comment: erfan golbahari, you didn't describe you question. What concrete problem do you have with you code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NET 4.0 you can use

```
public TResponse Send<TRequest, TResponse>(string url, TRequest request)
{
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
        using (var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
            {
                writer.Write(json);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        var responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        webResponse.Close();

                        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(responseData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw ProcessWebException(ex); // ToDo
        }
}
```

In NET 4.5 you can use

```
public async Task<TResponse> ExecuteAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(string url, TRequest request)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() {})
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
            var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var processResult = await client.PostAsync(url, httpContent);
            var responseBody = processResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(responseBody);
        }
    }
}
```

In example i use [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library.

Comment: What you mean by "how should i use net 4.5" ?

Comment: @AlekseiSemidotskii This is the solution I've searched the whole time! Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks very RAW, you should use some helpful libraries like [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) and [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp)